How to see face value by name?
I found that while debugging faces it's often useful to see whether the face even exists and if it does then what value it has.
I know there's a list-faces-display to list all defined faces, but it's kind of heavy, I'm wondering if there's a way to just evaluate the face in the Eval buffer by using some getter and see the current information about the face?

Use the face-all-attributes function:

(face-all-attributes FACE &optional FRAME)

Return an alist stating the attributes of FACE.  
Each element of the result has the form (ATTR-NAME . ATTR-VALUE).

E.g., (face-all-attributes 'link).
